# Как вызывать нестатический метод класса в PHP из статического?

Tags: php

Как вызывать нестатический метод класса в PHP из статического?

**Нужно вызвать NameB() из NameA**

```
class MyClass1
{
    public static function NameA()
    {

    }

    public function NameB()
    {
     //нужно вызвать NameB() из NameA
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем? Это противоречит самой сути статических методов.

Comment: Никак. Учите матчасть, а именно зачем нужны статические и не статические методы.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Никак?) Учите матчасть?) Вызвать можно. точка тире две точки, три тере, точка тире две точки.

Comment: @gilo1212 азбука Морзе?

Comment: @gilo1212, а теперь еще раз перечитайте мой комментарий выше. Вы видимо не понимаете **зачем** нужны статические методы и в чем их отличие от нестатических. Даже если php формально позволяет вам сделать какой-то бред, это вовсе не означает, что этот бред идеологически оправдан.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вопрос не в том, бред это или не бред, а в том, как можно это сделать.

Comment: @gilo1212 а вы хотите и дальше делать костыли и шлакоприложения и быть разрабом недоучкой или все же профессионалом своего дела?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class MyClass1
{
    public static function NameA()
    {
        self::NameB();
    }

    public function NameB()
    {
      echo 'ITS NAME B';
    }
}

MyClass1::NameA();
```

Вызвать можно, и он даже выведет `ITS NAME B`, **но так делать не следует!**

Но это является ошибкой стандарта статических методов, даже сам интерпритатор тебе об этом должен говорить.

`Strict standards: Non-static method MyClass1::NameB() should not be called statically`

Comment: То, что формально это работает вовсе не означает, что так стоит делать. Это как минимум чудовищный костыль.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я и не написал что можно работать и нужно работать. Я сказал что это приводит к ошибке, о которой говорит сам интерпритатор. И что это противоречит стандарту. Мои слова `Но это является ошибкой, даже сам интерпритатор тебе об этом должен говорить` говорят о том, что так делать не нужно. А минусить пост потому что ты меня не понял, очень не разумно

Comment: Во-первых это не ошибка а предупреждение. Во-вторых, интерпретатор может его и не выводить, все зависит от конкретных настроек php. Ну и в-третьих, я все равно не вижу чтобы вы _отговаривали_ ТС использовать этот путь. А раз так -- ваш совет можно считать вредным. За это и минус, а вовсе не за то, что я чего-то там не понял.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev поправил пост, но все равно, для меня warning так же как и ошибка, он должен быть исправлен.

Comment: В этом я с вами согласен. Но стоит учитывать, что большинству новичков проще отключить предупреждения (а ведь есть же еще и Notice). Как бы то ни было, +1

Comment: Кстати, эта фича уже deprecated в PHP7.0: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.static-calls

Comment: -1 так как ошибка вызов нестатичного метода как нестатичного, в конце концов можно сделать `$Obj = new self; $Obj->NameB(); `

Comment: @DmitriSimushev Она еще в 5.5 деприкэйтед

Comment: @Naumov `$Obj = new self; $Obj->NameB();` и в результате получите данные совсем другого экземпляра объекта. А если ум сего разработчика придумал план написать так: `$test = new MyClass1();
$test->NameA();` ?  С учетом вопроса я почему-то как раз в этом уверен)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мы можем годать сколько угодно до чего он додумался а до чего нет. В конце концов судя из примера контекст обекта и неважен

Comment: @Naumov и в правду, если создавать экземпляр класса, ошибок нет. Я об этом даже не подумал

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев дАдада - вызов через экземпляр класса) тоже можно кто то из вас уже написал - верно. Всем спасибо за участие)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ будет краток и прост. просто сделайте метод `public function NameB()`статичным и вызывайте его в конексте self
`public static function NameB()`

Comment: Не-не, архитектуру меня нельзя.

Comment: @gilo1212: То, что заставляет вызывать из статических методов нестатические, я бы поостерёгся называть _архитектурой_.

Comment: @Naumov Ну, спасибо за остренькое.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо вызвать нестатический метод, создайте для него временный объект:

```
class MyClass1
{
    public static function NameA()
    {
        $foo = new MyClass1;
        $foo->NameB();
    }

    public function NameB()
    {
        echo 'ITS NAME B';
    }
}

MyClass1::NameA();
```

Дело в том, что статические методы принадлежат классу в целом. То есть для их вызова достаточно знать только имя класса, а сами эти методы отличаются от обычных функций только именем (включающим в себя не только собственное имя, но и имя класса).

Нестатические же методы принадлежат уже конкретному экземпляру класса. То есть для их вызова нам необходим объект. Именно к нему применяется метод, и именно его поля доступны изнутри метода через локальную переменную `self`.